# How to print a missing category in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a sample datafarame below:

```
df <- data.frame(Grade = c(1,1,2,2,2),
                 Var = c("Gender","Gender","Gender","Gender","Gender"),
                 Cat = c("No","Not Specified", "No","Yes","Not Sepcified"),
                 n = c(10,15,20,40,40),
                 Percentage = c(.40,.60,.2,.4,.4))

> df
  Grade    Var           Cat  n Percentage
1     1 Gender            No 10        0.4
2     1 Gender Not Sepcified 15        0.6
3     2 Gender            No 20        0.2
4     2 Gender           Yes 40        0.4
5     2 Gender Not Specified 40        0.4
```

`Grade = 1` has the Cat of `Yes` missing while `Grade = 2` has all categories available in the data. I would like to modify the outcome to present the `Yes` Category as `0` in `n` and Percentage category. How can I achieve the desired outcome as below:

```
> df_desired
  Grade    Var           Cat  n Percentage
1     1 Gender            No 10        0.4
1.    1 Gender           Yes  0        0
2     1 Gender Not Sepcified 15        0.6
3     2 Gender            No 20        0.2
4     2 Gender           Yes 40        0.4
5     2 Gender Not Specified 40        0.4
```

Comment: The `tidyr::complete` function can take care of adding rows for missing observations: `tidyr::complete(df, Grade,Var, Cat, fill=list(n=0, Percentage=0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```r
df <- data.frame(Grade = c(1,1,2,2,2),
                 Var = c("Gender","Gender","Gender","Gender","Gender"),
                 Cat = c("No","Not Specified", "No","Yes","Not Specified"),
                 n = c(10,15,20,40,40),
                 Percentage = c(.40,.60,.2,.4,.4))

df %>% expand(Grade,Var,Cat) %>% left_join(df, join_by(Grade,Var,Cat)) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(n,Percentage), ~ ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .)))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  Grade Var    Cat               n Percentage
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>         <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1 Gender No               10        0.4
2     1 Gender Not Specified    15        0.6
3     1 Gender Yes               0        0  
4     2 Gender No               20        0.2
5     2 Gender Not Specified    40        0.4
6     2 Gender Yes              40        0.4
```